# Java .contains method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, contains

I create an arraylist full of "states" but can't find states in the list after they have been added

```
public class State {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public State(int a,int b,int c) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Then in the main class

```
public class Main {
    static ArrayList<State> nodes = new ArrayList<State>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      State randomState = new State(12,0,0);
      nodes.add(randomState);
      System.out.println(nodes.contains(new State(12,0,0)));
    }      
}
```

This would return false but if i do

```
System.out.println(nodes.contains(randomState));
```

would return true.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) relies on the `equals()` method of the objects :

> More formally, **returns true** if and only if this list contains at
>   least one element e **`such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`**.

Override it and `hashCode()` in the `State` class such as :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof State)) return false;
    State state = (State) o;
    return a == state.a &&
            b == state.b &&
            c == state.c;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(a, b, c);
}
```

Or don't use this method and perform the search yourself.
For example :

```
public boolean isAnyMatch(List<State> states, State other){   
  return states.stream()
               .anyMatch(s -> s.getA() == other.getA() && 
                         s.getB() == other.getB()  && 
                         s.getC() == other.getC() )
}


System.out.println(isAnyMatch(nodes, new State(12,0,0));
```

Comment: You, you know how to welcome your pairs :)